# Word for a software bug that occurs again after having fixed it?

Tags: word-choice, software, software-bugs

What's the word for a software bug that reoccurs after being fixed?

I'm embarking on some test-driven development (TDD) for a project, and I want to use the right term but have forgotten the word.

It's not *reversion*, but I think it sounds similar.

Though I've used it many times I can't recollect the term right now, and Google isn't helping me.

*Addition 1: The bug is imaginary in this case. It only reappears once, after I fixed, because of a new change I introduce. I'm not talking about something that that keeps on popping up.*

Addition 2: The correct answer popped up *7 minutes* after asking. The amount of bikeshedding the keeps on coming after that is hilarious.

Comment: *[Gremlins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin).* Clearly something is immanent in the code and keeps getting reborn.

Comment: I usually use the term insidious, but that's an adjective and not an answer to the noun synonym for a reoccurring bug.

Comment: If it occurs again, it was never *really* fixed (or was reintroduced).

Comment: but it can be understood that there are bugs that are difficult to pin down, so you believe that a solution will fix it, but doesn't.  The bug report is closed, and it might even work for a while, and then somewhat mysteriously happens again, so then another solution is proposed.  The OP is looking for a word to describe that type of bug, and these situations do exist since the world isn't perfect.  (even though it was "never really fixed")

Comment: ***Unfixed***...

Comment: FYI, I think you mean "test *driven* development."

Comment: ***reopened***.

Comment: mistake, misunderstand, or misinterpret? If the software bug occurs again, then was it really ever fixed? "The problem is we don't understand the problem." http://uxmag.com/articles/you-are-solving-the-wrong-problem

Comment: If the bug is still there then, by definition, it wasn't fixed.

Comment: At that point, we generally call it a feature.

Comment: has this not been linked here yet?  http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/

Comment: Perhaps such things should be called a Phoenix Bug

Comment: I wouldn't really describe that as *bikeshedding*, it's more like, "XY problem" or similar.  The issue you allude to is similar (but not identical) to this issue .. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193787/single-word-or-good-words-phrase-for-confusingly-asked-question-where-meaning

Comment: thanks for asking this, my mind was stuck too and Google didn't help as you said (too many irrelevant results)

Comment: I suspect many programmers would call it "that m&%#@! f#^*!@& bug!!"

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You're looking for "***regression***".

Comment: Regression refers not uniquely to bugs that occur again after fixing. Though the OP was probably looking for this word without knowing its actual meaning.

Comment: I think of *regression* as meaning a bug that was introduced as part of new changes (matching e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression), which is not quite the word the OP is looking for. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regression does define it as the OP's word (almost the same terms, even!), though, so there are multiple definitions.

Comment: Happy to add that **regression** was definitely the word I was looking for. Also very cool that this answer came within 7 minutes after posting. All the rest is mere fluff. Nice fluff though, especially *mandelbug*.

Comment: @KasperSouren I would contend that the difference between "regression" and "recurring bugs" is not just "fluff"--you may already understand the difference, but if not, do some more reading on the subject!! Regression testing is an extremely important concept. (Possibly more importantly, true TDD tests share aspects of unit tests, regression tests, and acceptance tests, but are [ultimately slightly different](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/11/tdd-tests-are-not-unit-tests) from all three.)

Comment: @TimS. I don't "regression" is the right word for this context either. "Regression bugs occur whenever software functionality that previously worked as desired stops working, or no longer works as planned. Typically regression bugs occur as an unintended consequence of program changes." http://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/Workshops/verification2007/present/Dor_Nir_web.pdf --

Comment: The context is 1/. that the OP fixes a bug, 2/. he then creates a regression test when submitting this bug fix.  3/. Then the OP or another make another change, 4/. at that point the regressions test should be run and then they should highlight if the bug has "re-entered" the code base and is expressed by the regression test failing.  I would call it a "re-entrant" bug, but the process to stop this is called regression test, once there is a bug, and you fix it, make sure it's fixed for all time.

Comment: For all the commenters who are troubled by "*regression*", let me offer "*relapse*" ;)

Comment: @MichaelStoner calling it reentrant would risk confusion with the idea of reentrant functions, as in, 'the function is meant to be reentrant, but the test demonstrates that it is not.'

Comment: @atk yes, that's correct. It's regression tests should reduce reoccurring bugs

Comment: "Happy to add that regression was definitely the word I was looking for" it may have been the word you were looking for, but it is utterly incorrect.  As @Vilmar says **"the OP was probably looking for this word without knowing its actual meaning"**

Comment: @Dan I guess your answer is **literally** correct in that the OP was "looking for..." "regression".  I feel you could have avoided much pointless commenting by everyone, if you'd added a couple words preamble or examble, such as "You're looking for the word 'regression', but you have the meaning mixed-up a little."  Cheers

Comment: The meaning is not mixed up.  One common meaning of the word "regression" is exactly what the OP asked for.  Definitions like "a bug that was introduced as part of new changes" are simply alternate, related meanings.

Comment: @JoeBlow The article on software regression isn't great, but one that it links to is better: [Regression testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing).  While the question is a bit muddled in that the *bug* isn't quite regression, it's the kind of bug that's *caught* by a regression test.  It's the *behavior* of the software that has regressed.

Answer (score 27):

Such bugs may simply be called *recurring bugs*. There are even [papers](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1806847) on such bugs:

> Previous research confirms the existence of recurring bug fixes in software systems...

Comment: "Recurring bug fixes" is ambiguous.  Is it the bug that recurs, or is it the fix?

Comment: @WalterMitty: Syntactically it is "recurring {bug fix}" (with *recurring* modifying *bug fix*, rather than *recurring bug* modifying *fix*), but semantically the ambiguity is not that great anyway, since a bug fix can only recur if the bug did, and a bug cannot really "recur", *per se*, if it isn't fixed in between. Almost the only real difference is that \*"{recurring bug} fix" might not imply that the same fix was used each time the bug recurred.

Comment: @WalterMitty Lol. Well you can't have a bug fix without a bug, so saying recurring bug fixes implies recurring bugs.

Answer (score 20):

The bug was *reintroduced* by a subsequent change, resulting in a *regression*.

Comment: Regression doesn't mean the same thing to a statistician and to a child psychologist.

Comment: @WalterMitty which does not invalidate the answer in any way, just two different uses for the same word, plenty of examples of that. If talking about a *bug regression* the context is 100% clear.

Comment: Fair enough.  "regression" is short for "bug regression".  Works for me.

Answer (score 10):

UNFIXED.

And that is not the same as regression error. If you try to fix something, deploy it, and it turns out not to be fixed, then it was never fixed!  period.

Regression error is when the fix attempt BROKE SOMETHING ELSE THAT PREVIOUSLY WORKED, hence that "something" has regressed.

Comment: I don't think you read the question (or maybe it was edited?) ... the question clearly indicates that the bug was fixed and then recurs.

Comment: Well, if it was really fixed then it wouldn't occur again. It was being fixed, someone has tried to fix it, even though he or she had fixed it, but eventually the bug hasn't been fixed.

Comment: I say this is the answer for the version of the question I see.  If you tried to fix it but just recently found a new set of circumstances that causes the same issue, it was either an unfixed bug  or an attempt at fixing a bug that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Someone wrote the faulty code the first time and that lead to some particular *symptom*.  That particular code got fixed.  Then someone writes some more code which contains a new bug, but which causes the same symptom.  The *behavior* of the software has *regressed*.  The idea is that the regression test that was created with the original bug fix catches this regression in behavior.  See [regression testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing): "it is … good coding practice, when a bug is located and fixed, to record a test that exposes the bug and re-run that test regularly".

Comment: It's also possible to come up with a fix that conceals the symptom, but doesn't really fix the underlying problem.  When that is done, the symptom is likely to show up again, in a slightly different context.

Comment: One not too uncommon alternative is that the bug was fixed but an other developer's update to the repository inserts an older version of the code where the bug exists.

Answer (score 7):

A *mandelbug* (named after Benoît Mandelbrot's fractal) is a bug whose causes are so complex that it defies repair, or makes its behavior appear chaotic or even non-deterministic.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: This is a true statement, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: It is very interesting that you link to an article that says that **Heisenbug** is the common term for this. Even in its title.

Comment: I've hear the term Mandelbug more commonly in my experience and is a better example of what the OP was asking for.  Heisenbug, I feel, refers to a bug that can not easily be tracked down, where the Mandelbug has so many permutations, that a fix in one place causes similar breakage in other places.

Comment: @oerkelens: no, the article defines "Heisenbug" and "Mandelbug" to be different things. It's just that for whatever reason they're part of a single article.

Comment: @SteveJessop - Having examined Wikipedia's protocols as part of my research I can tell you that the reason the two topics are part of a single article is because they have rules that _prevent_ any subject from having its own article unless certain criteria are met, but _allow_ closely related topics to be subjects _within_ an existing page that has already met those criteria. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notability) for a trip down the rabbit hole but be warned you probably will wish you had taken the [blue pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_pill_and_blue_pill). :)

Answer (score 6):

The answer to *the actual question as asked:*

(1) When you've thought you fixed a bug, but you had not fixed it: there ***is no*** particular slang or term for this..

You would simply say it is **unfixed, reopened, or "not yet fixed"**.

(2) The word on the tip of your tongue was apparently "regression".

**NOTE:** "regression" has utterly no connection to what the question asks. It has no connection, in any way, to issue (1).

Footnote: the two wikipedia pages are/were completely useless. They have since been fixed to some extent.

Comment: +1 @JoeBlow, agreed. It's easy for a monkey "software engineer" to flag it as fixed when it isn't, especially when they don't have thorough test coverage or even use unit testing at all. In this case it did not "regress", i.e. 'revert to an earlier ... behavioral level' (Merriam-Webster) but rather, was never fixed. "Re-opened" seems to be the best description seeing as it was erroneously marked "fixed".

Comment: And, of course, if your code management is sufficiently rotten, you can get the fix removed from the latest code by a phantom code update.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [regression testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing) is better than the one on **software regression**, and while the *bug* isn't a regression (it's the behavior of the software that's regressed), it's a *regression test* that would catch it: "it is considered good coding practice, when a bug is located and fixed, to record a test that exposes the bug and re-run that test regularly after subsequent changes to the program."

Comment: Also, from that same article: "Often, a fix for a problem will be “fragile” in that it fixes the problem in the narrow case where it was first observed but not in more general cases which may arise over the lifetime of the software. Frequently, a fix for a problem in one area inadvertently causes a software bug in another area. Finally, it may happen that, when some feature is redesigned, some of the same mistakes that were made in the original implementation of the feature are made in the redesign."  Thus why OP thought of "regression", even though the bug itself isn't quite the regression.

Comment: When you get rid of horrifically useless wikipedia pages, they seem to pop up again in a few days.  ;)

Comment: lol on that Walter  :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible alternative, assuming the bug was seemingly fixed until a later change proved otherwise, would be to say the bug has ***reasserted*** itself.